# how to use Regex in AssetDatabase.FindAssets()?

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine

i tried to use AssetDatabase.FindAssets() to find a scriptableObject inside a specific file, im looking for a file named Resource. and i want to take every scriptable object inside all the Resource file scattered in my Assets folder.

for example :

Assets/GameAssets/FolderA/Resource/AssetA.asset

Assets/GameAssets/FolderB/Resource/AssetB.asset

Assets/GameAssets/FolderC/Resource/AssetC.asset

Assets/GameAssets/FolderD/Resource/AssetD.asset

this is the current code that I use

`AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:ScriptableObject", new[] { "Assets/GameAssets" });`

it would return unwanted scriptableObjects. then I tried adding regex

`AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:ScriptableObject", new[] { "Assets/GameAssets/*/Resource/AssetD.asset" });`

ofc it failed, im inexperienced and need help.

Comment: You can iterate through all assets and check if **Directory.GetParent(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath('currentIteration')).name == "Resource"**

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [`Directory.GetDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories) like

```
var resourceFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(Application.assetPath,"Games sets"), "Resource", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

which recursively finds all paths of directories called `Resource` within the `Assets/GameAssets` directory.

And then do

```
var assets = new List<string>();
foreach(var folder in resourceFolders)
{
    assets.AdsRange(AssetDatabass.FindAssets("t:ScriptableObject", folder);
}
```

in order to do individual searches for each of these `Resource` directories.